# Как получить данные с сайта кодом расширения?

Tags: javascript, браузер, расширения

Расширение гугл хром, нужно что бы при открытии расширения отправлялся запрос на страницу и получал html. 
Но проблема вот в чем: нужно что бы отправлялось на авторизированную страницу. 
Простой пример: 
Есть один сайт, если я его открываю, он заходит на мою страницу уже авторизированным, но когда я получаю html в расширении через js он не загружает мои данные, а просто бесконечно получает данные с сервера. 
Есть ли возможность получать данные авторизированного пользователя на js? Может плагины, или я что-то делаю не так. 
Надеюсь, понятно описал.
Если проще, нужно парсить страницу авторизированного пользователя, да так что бы он не вводил логин и пароль.

Comment: Нет, не понятно описали. Распишите подробнее и нагляднее, чего вы хотите добиться?

Comment: Кросс доменные запросы - запрещены по умолчанию из соображений безопасности, так что на JS - нельзя.

Comment: Нужно на своем сервере написать скрипт, который курлом возьмет данные авторизованного пользователя передавая все куки и заголовки для входа.